# How can I use place_meeting to determine if two objects are no longer colliding in GameMaker Studio?

Tags: game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I have an object called static_world_object, which I intend to be the parent of objects that are inanimate. I added code in the step event which I intend to check to see if a player object is currently colliding with it.

```
if self.image_alpha < 1{ // Checks to see if the static object has become transparent

    var obj_player_instance;
    obj_player_instance = instance_find(obj_player,0);

    if !place_meeting(obj_player_instance.x, obj_player_instance.y, self){
        show_debug_message("A");}
    else{
        show_debug_message("B");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

In the images added to the question, it can be seen that no matter whether I'm colliding with the inanimate object or not, it always logs "A".

What am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried `!place_meeting(x, y, obj_player_instance)`? And is the child object inheriting the Step Event of that parent object? Another thing that may take a role is the Origin point that `x` and `y` refers to, and that point is by default the top-left position of the sprite.

Comment: @Steven !place_meeting(x, y, obj_player_instance) worked perfectly. I don't know why swapping the instances around like that makes it work, but I guess I'll learn over time. Thanks a bunch Steven!

Comment: No problem! what I think is the cause is that the parameter in `self` will only refer to it's instance, and not the personal object that itself is.